# geometric sequences formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the formula $a_n = a_1\cdot r^{n-1}$ always applied to geometric sequences no matter what the case. i.e. can I rely on using this formula to solve any geometric equation or does it only apply to some?

Comment: How are you defining a geometric sequence?

Comment: "A geometric sequence goes from one term to the next by always multiplying (or dividing) by the same value." - http://www.purplemath.com/modules/series3.htm

Comment: Ok...so if $a_2=a_1\times r$ then $a_3=a_2\times r = a_1\times r^2$ and so on.

Comment: no a2 = a1*r^2-1 and then same concept applies to a3 with 3-1

Comment: How does that differ from what I wrote?

Comment: the common ratio 'r' is to the power of n-1, in the example of n being 2, you have to do 2-1, which leaves you with a1*r^1

Comment: Yes, which is what I wrote.  Since $2-1=1$ writing $r^{2-1}$ is the same as writing $r^1$ or just $r$.  I'm really not seeing your point here.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I thought you wern't implying that r is the same as r^1 because you didnt really show any working out.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with a geometric sequence $(a_n)_n$ where
$$a_n = ra_{n-1} \qquad \text{for all } n\in \mathbf N_{\geq 2}$$
you can write
$$a_n= r^{n-1} a_1.$$
The formula for $a_n$ can be easily shown by induction:
$$a_n = ra_{n-1} = r^2 a_{n-2} = \dotsc=r^{n-2} a_2 = r^{n-1} a_1.$$